# RestFB get events in Java

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

Using FQL, by means of which finds events that contain a given word. FQL works only in API version <2.1.   By which I use the Graph API Explorer to display events. Eg.

```
search?q=york&type=event
```

Example of FQL

```
SELECT Eid, name, location, start_time, description, pic_small, creator, event venue FROM WHERE start_time> "Sun Jun 21 0:00:35 GMT 2015" AND (CONTAINS ("york")
```

I would like to make a search events by using RestFB not using FQL, but do not know how. The documentation is scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this already on github, but perhaps someone else find this useful.

Your special case is not in the documentation, but you can transfer the knowledge you find in the documentation and solve your problem: http://restfb.com/#searching

```
Connection<Event> eventList = 
    facebookClient.fetchConnection("search", Event.class,
    Parameter.with("q", "york"), Parameter.with("type", "event"));
```

Now, you can iterate over the `eventList`. 
Here you can find how this can be done: http://restfb.com/#fetching-connections